# No Host only adapter selected

Tags: virtualbox

I have a problem with my virtualbox on ubuntu 12.04, I can't add a host only adapter, the message is "no host only network adapter selected" I can't select anything

[image]

can anyone solve this problem??

Comment: Can you attach it to eth0?

Comment: yes I can. but with bridge not with host only

Comment: I really recommend restarting if you're hosting on windows. (my VM is Ubuntu)
That's what fixed mine, even after trying all the other stuff above. [before restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXrca.png) [after restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yti2A.png)

Answer (score 200, accepted):

Probably, the virtual host-only network wasn't set up yet. Here's is how you can fix this if you have a version older than 2018:

1. From the main menu, select File > Preferences (Ctrl+G) - NOT the settings of a single vm
2. Select Network in the list on the left
3. You should see an empty white box with "Host-only Networks" at the top. On the right, there are three buttons to manage them. Click the topmost one (with a green plus symbol). A new Host-only network will be created and added to the list.

[image: screenshoot]

Normally, the settings of the new network will be ok, but for completeness, I give the default values here. You can access the settings for the host-only network through the screwdriver button on the right.

[image: ss2]

- Adapter:

  - IPv4 address: 192.168.56.1
  - IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
- DHCP server:

  - Enable server: checked
  - Server Address: 192.168.56.100
  - Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
  - Lower Address Bound: 192.168.56.101
  - Upper Address Bound: 192.168.56.254

You can change these settings to your liking, as long as they're consistent.

Comment: thanks you,,, you have solved my problem . . . .  usually I use virtual box in windows,, but now I have to use it on linux. . . . . . I'ts really different. . . .

Comment: You are life saver

Comment: In 2018, you have to go to `File -> Host Network Manager`.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith can you make that an answer. Or update this answer please. Thanks!!

Comment: In 2019, you have to go to `File -> Host Network Manager`

Comment: @LorenzoLerate I think we can just say it is like that since 2018 instead of adding a comment for each year :D

Comment: In 2020, you have to go to `File -> Host Network Manager`

Comment: In 2021, you have to go to `File -> Host Network Manager`.

Comment: In 2022, you have to go to `File -> Host Network Manager` asd

Comment: Later in 2022, you have to go to `File -> Tools -> Network Manager`

Comment: In 2023, same way `file -> Tools -> Network Manager`

Answer (score 37):

I installed virtual box recently and its different,

After Virtual Box is open, click on File>Host Network Manager>Add. This will add the 192.168.56.1/24 IP as shown above.

Now you can see vboxnet0 in the "Name" dropdown in the VM.

Comment: yep, you are right, in newer versions the host networks has desappeared from the usual Network preferences

Comment: Thank you. An extra note for others: This solution works for the following specs: VirtualBox v.6 , Ubuntu 16.04 , Catalina MacOS (specifically for OpenDayLight if you want to connect to mininet VM) .

Comment: Thank you for this information.  I just did a fresh reinstall of my Host OS and suddenly found this feature of VB6 inexplicably no longer working.  It's frustrating when older tutorials point to a tab that's no longer there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked straight forward

Comment: Provided snapshot here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934711/virtual-box-host-only-network-interface/69060794#69060794

Answer (score 17):

For those, who are in trouble finding "Host-only Networks" tab in *File->Preferences->Network*.

After the version VirtualBox 5.2.0, there are some changes with the location of  "Host-only Networks" tab.

This tool is moved on the main UI toolbar, specifically the **Global Tools** split button on the right.

Alternatively, you can access it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, or *File->Host Network Manager* menu.

Source: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=85464

Answer (score 8):

In 2020, a few changes.

1. From the main menu select file

[image]

2. Select Host Network Manager

[image]

3. Select create

[image]

This would create the settings of the new network, check the "Enable DHCP Server". Now go back to network settings it should see the name of the newly created network when you select Host-only Adapter.