# No network on virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I can't connect to Internet from my virtualbox. This is my first attempt with a virtual machine so I am not sure what might be useful to mention, but here are some stuff I noticed or will hopefully be helpful:

- I have Ubuntu (12.04) as host and Debian on virtualbox.
- The browser fails to execute due to Input/output error.
- I have tried to attach Adapter 1 with all options and non worked.
- When I try to enable Adapter 2, there is a red message "no host-only network adapter is selected"
- On my host machine, when I use -ifconfig -a, there is no indication of the virtualbox
- I don't know what else to check or try...

Does anybody knows what might be the problem?

Comment: I think that the solution you're looking is here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/198452/no-host-only-adapter-selected Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are many modes of networking in virtual box. If you have internet in you host the easiest is to make it NAT as the image below.

[image]

There are many modes to do also. You can make it bridged and assign an ip to the client OS.

To learn more about networking in virtual box please refer to [this](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) and [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/networking_in_virtualbox1).

Comment: What I meant by saying that I tried to attach Adapter 1 with all options was that I have already tried NAT and bridged and actually all the available modes. That's why I asked my question here. Something is still wrong.